# Build Android NDK toolchain on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, build, android-ndk, toolchain

does anyone know how to build the Android NDK toolchain on Mac OS X? I found this guide for Linux & Windows: http://recursify.com/blog/2013/08/08/building-an-android-ndk-toolchain but no luck for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide to build NDK toolchain. It mentions *Darwin* so you may be able to build the toolchain on OS X.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/tools/DEV-SCRIPTS-USAGE.TXT

Answer (score 1):

Move to $NDK/build/tools, and:

- **For Mac OS X, use this**

  /Users/**user**/android-ndk-r10d/build/tools$ ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=/tmp/my-toolchain --ndk-dir=/Users/**user**/android-ndk-r10d/ --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --system=darwin-x86_64
- I've needed some args more in a **Ubuntu OS**:

  /home/**user**/android-ndk-r10d/build/tools$ ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=/tmp/my-toolchain --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --system=linux-x86_64

Don't forget to change the 'user' by your real username.

Comment: make-standalone-toolchain.sh is not for building NDK toolchain. "Generate a customized Android toolchain installation that includes a working sysroot. The result is something that can more easily be used as a standalone cross-compiler".